# Create private composite Github action that runs a python script and is called from another private repo

Tags: python, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a Python script that I want to run as a final deployment step from several of my repos. Since this script uses the Github API I wanted to abstract all of this logic into its own github action (thus its own separate repo). [Since Dec-22](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-14-github-actions-sharing-actions-and-reusable-workflows-from-private-repositories-is-now-ga/) it's possible to share between private repos to all Github users. I've already updated my action repo with the appropriate setting to be accessed from internal repos to the organization.

I have two repos:

- `org/my-action`: the github action repo, containing the python script
- `org/core`: repo from which I want to trigger `my-action`

My `action.yml` from `org/my-action` looks like this:

```yaml
name: Release to Calendar
inputs:
  calendar-id:
    description: 'Unique identifier'
    required: true

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
    with:
      python-version: '3.11'
  - name: Install dependencies
    shell: "bash"
    run: pip install -r requirements.txt
  - name: Create calendar event
    shell: "bash"
    run: python main.py ${{inputs.calendar-id}}
```

The workflow in `org/core` that invokes my action looks like this:

```yaml
name: release to calendar

on:
  workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  to-calendar:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: org/my-action@main
        with:
          calendar-id: 'some value'
```

However, the `actions/checkout` step starts checking out my `org/core` repo instead, and then running pip installs the requirements from the `core` repo as well.

To fix this, I updated my action to look like this:

```yaml
name: Release to Calendar
inputs:
  calendar-id:
    description: 'Unique identifier'
    required: true

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      repository: 'org/my-action'
      ref: 'main'
      path: 'calendar-action'

  - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
    with:
      python-version: '3.11'
  - name: Install dependencies
    shell: "bash"
    run: pip install -r calendar-action/requirements.txt
  - name: Create calendar event
    shell: "bash"
    run: python calendar-action/main.py ${{inputs.calendar-id}}
```

But now I get the message: `Error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/org/my-action' not found`.

I understand that I could [create a PAT][3] and use that as a secret in one of the repos (not sure which one) but is this the only way to go? It seems redundant to create a token that will give repo access to "itself", in a sense. It is possible that I'm misunderstanding fundamentally how actions work: Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Creating a PAT would resolve the problem. Did you also evaluate creating a `reusable` workflow instead of a `composite action`? The solution might be easier in your case.

Comment: @GuiFalourd A reusable workflow would also work but I'd like this functionality to be available to three other independent repositories: I guess in that scenario I still would need to check out the action/script repo and then also handle PATs. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.